# DOMDocument is not returning objects from CURL

Tags: php, dom, curl, domdocument

I wrote this code to parse the title of `craigslist` website.

```
<?php  

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://craigslist.org/about/sites");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
$cl = curl_exec($ch);

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
@$dom->loadHTML($cl);

$title = $dom -> getElementById("logo");
echo $title->nodeValue;

?>
```

But it shows an error:

`Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\products\index.php on line 13`

Where did I messed up?

Comment: @$dom->loadHTML($cl); 
Why are you using the @ on this line? Is $cl returning false?

Comment: @JoshuaBixler it omits the warning like this: `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Document is empty in Entity, line: 1`. It will only show the error notice like what I've stated above.

Comment: Your line number doesn't match up. Can you show more code, or explain where exactly you're getting the error?

Comment: Does curl_error have an error message? http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php It sounds like curl_exec is returning false meaning there was an error.

Comment: @oliakaoil question edited.

Comment: @JoshuaBixler no, there was no curl error because when I write the code like this, 
`$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://craigslist.org/about/sites");
curl_exec($ch);` it will display the page. Therefore the `curl_exec()` executes is well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
 <?php
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://craigslist.org/about/sites");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
 $cl = curl_exec($ch);

 $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
 @$dom->loadHTML($cl);

 $title = $dom -> getElementById("logo");
 echo $title->nodeValue;
```

I used `curl_getinfo` along with your initial code to see more information about the HTTP response, and was getting a 302 redirect as an HTTP response code. You can follow redirects with cURL by setting the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` option.